# Firestore Rules Won't Be Used For Requests From C#

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am making a WPF App and i'm using Firestore with this app. Problem is that when i write a new value to Firestore, it let me write although Firestore rules are set to 'false'. So Firestore rules are not working but i need them to work.

This is my C# code;

```
Dictionary<string, object> user = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "text", "aaaa" },
                };
            await db.Collection("deneme").Document("doc").SetAsync(user);
```

and this is my Firestore Rules;

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to make some rules that let users write and get only their own Datas.

I'm new to C#

Comment: Security rules only apply to requests coming from web and mobile apps where Firebase Auth is being used, or the REST API if you provide a Firebase Auth user token.  They don't apply to the other SDKs used primarily with backend code.

Comment: Is there any specific error showing? if yes please share

Comment: specify ur error and put ur complete code here

Comment: @DougStevenson so anyone who decompile my WPF app and get my Firebase API key can steal datas? How should i protect my datas?

Comment: @SachithWickramaarachchi there is no problem like you say. What i want is told at the first comment.

Comment: That API key is meant to be in the client app.  Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you but actually i have read this before but i'm still confused. Basically will it be safe to connect my WPF app to firebase and publish my app on the store?

Comment: I don't know.  I can't see everything you've done. I can tell you that there are thousands of Android, iOS, and web apps all with their API keys visible to the public that are correctly configured to be secure.

Comment: Well actually i use Firebase authentication and for that i need my API keys

`FirebaseAuthProvider authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig("AIzaSyBqroqPb2...................."));` 

So this will be safe in this way? @DougStevenson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, i have used REST API